# What is the minimum length for a UUID?

Tags: uuid

From general observation I've come across the standard to be 36. I was looking to incorporate a uuid in my urls but didn't want it that long. Is there a minimum where I can still keep the uuid unique?

Comment: Just use the standard uuid. Smart people spent a lot of time thinking about how it should be. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/04/24/guid-guide-part-one/

Comment: Don't make the mistake of trying to split a generated UUID though.  Some components of a UUID include year and other "static" information that might make your split UUID well, no longer universal (UID?).  If you have no reason to use UUID, then a sequential numeric counter should work just fine.

Comment: Do yourself and everyone a favour and use the existing standard. Anything else is likely to cause you, your successor, or your customers trouble.

Answer (score 6):

Behind the scenes, a UUID is just a 128-bit number.  The 32 hex characters, plus four dashes, is just a friendlier version for readability.

If you re-pack the 128 bits into a different format, you could produce something a bit shorter.  For instance, base-64 would only require 22 characters.

Sticking with a standard UUID has several advantages:-

- All common desktop or server operating systems should come with a library call to generate a UUID.
- On any given machine, all UUIDs will be unique.
- If you move to a different machine, the odds of that new machine generating the same UUID as a previous one are vanishingly small.

Comment: The idea is that UUIDs are globally unique. Enforced by having 2^128 different ones.

Comment: "UUID is just a 128-bit number" - that's not behind the scenes, that's the presentation.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for interoperability, then you'll have to use the standard UUID format. If your system will be the only consumer of your ID, then you can make choices, but the choices will depend upon your detailed needs.

For instance, if you can allocate your IDs sequentially, with no chance of collision (other than wrap-around) then you can pick an IDs-per-second value times the lifetime of your product, and then multiply by a safety ratio, to get the highest ID you need to accommodate. For example, if you estimate that one ID will be generated per second at most, and you need a ten year lifetime, and have a safety ratio of 10, then that's only about 2^32 IDs, which is a quarter the usual length.

However, if your IDs will be allocated randomly, and you still need a vanishingly-small chance of collision (it'll never be zero), then your ID length must be much greater, and in fact a standard UUID might be the way to go.

In other circumstances, even 2^32 IDs would be overkill. Again, it all depends upon your detailed needs.